# Cómo acceder desde otros ficheros a un objeto creado en main? Arduino, c++

Tags: c++, arduino, vscode

Qué tal, estoy usando Visual Studio Code 2019 para crear un programa en c++ para Arduino cuyo fin es interactuar con un lector de tarjetas RFID. Dado que se incluirán algunos dispositivos extras (display, buzzer, RTC), tengo la idea de incluir en el archivo principal únicamente las librerías y configuraciones, y crear el resto de funciones en archivos separados para únicamente llamarlos desde el loop principal, por lo que la estructura de los archivos luciría algo así:

1. Main.cpp -
2. AutenticarTarjeta.h
3. LeerTarjeta.h
4. EscribirTarjeta.h
   etc

En mi código, declaro la librería del lector y creo el objeto RC522 en el main, justo antes del void setup()

Main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <MFRC522_I2C.h>
#define RST_PIN 14
MFRC522 RC522(0x28, RST_PIN); //Creación de objeto RC522

#include <WiFi.h>
#include "GananciaAntena.h"

/* DC: Creación de instancia RC522 */
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key AuthKey;
MFRC522::StatusCode OperationStatus;

/* DC: Credenciales de red para conexión WiFi*/
const char *SSID = "DESARROLLO";
const char *Password = "&Tinto150000&";

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Sin embargo, al llamarlo dentro del archivo "GananciaAntena.h", obtengo un error ya que en ese fichero, el objeto RC522 no existe.

GananciaAntena.h:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void GananciaAntena(int NivelPotencia) {
  byte RxGain;

  switch (NivelPotencia) {

  case 0: {
    RxGain = 0x00;
    break;
  }

  case 1: {
    RxGain = 0x01;
    break;
  }

  case 2: {
    RxGain = 0x04;
    break;
  }

  case 3: {
    RxGain = 0x05;
    break;
  }

  case 4: {
    RxGain = 0x06;
    break;
  }

  case 5: {
    RxGain = 0x07;
    break;
  }

  default: {
    RxGain = 0x00;
    break;
  }
  }

  RC522.PCD_SetRegisterBitMask(RC522.RFCfgReg, (RxGain << 4));
}
```

¿Cómo hago para volver visible dentro de otros ficheros un objeto creado en el programa principal?

Comment: Entendido. Formato corregido

Answer (score 0):

Como tu mismo has dicho, el compilador no sabe lo que es tu variable; así que tienes que decírselo. Pero decirlo con claridad y de forma completa: tienes un tipo X, y una instancia de nombre Y declarada en algún sitio.

Para ello, C++ incorpora la palabra reservada [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Aunque la documentación pueda parecer *complicadilla*, en la práctica es mucho mas simple de lo que parece.

Normalmente, usaremos un archivo de cabecera adicional para ello, por ejemplo, `main.hpp`:

```
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#include <MFRC522_I2C.h>

extern MFRC522 RC522;

#endif
```

Ahora ya solo te queda incluir tu nuevo archivo de cabecera allá donde lo necesites.

Esta forma tiene un ligero ... *inconveniente*: **el orden de instanciación de objectos es indefinido entre módulos**. Eso quiere decir que puede darse el caso de que intentes usar la instancia ... **antes** de que se cree. Esto solo puede pasar desde código que se ejecuta antes de entrar en el `main( )`, principalmente constructores de objetos estáticos (tales como tu propio objeto RC522).

En estos casos, puedes usar una función *envoltura* para proteger el acceso a tu instancia; modificamos tu archivo `main.cpp`:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <MFRC522_I2C.h>
#define RST_PIN 14

MFRC522 &SingleRC522( ) {
    static RC522(0x28, RST_PIN); //Creación de objeto RC522

    return RC522;
}

// ... resto del código de main.cpp ...
```

Y, en el `main.hpp`, en lugar de declarar la instancia, hacemos lo propio con la función:

```
#ifndef MAIN_HPP
#define MAIN_HPP

#include <MFRC522_I2C.h>

MFRC522 &SingleRC522( );

#endif
```

Ahora, ya puedes acceder sin peligro a tu objeto `RC522` simplemente llamando a la función `SingleRC522( )` desde cualquier parte de tu código.

Esto funciona porque, en el caso de variables estáticas **dentro de una función**, el lenguaje **garantiza** que la instancia se creará **antes** de su primer uso: la tendrás disponible en cuanto intentes devolverla con el `return`.

Comment: Recapitulando:

Declaro el objeto RC522 junto con su librería y pines en el archivo "main.cpp", adicionalmente creo otro fichero que incluya el bloque de código que me comentaste (main.hpp), y posteriormente, cuando necesite referenciar el objeto RC522 desde otro archivo (GananciaAntena.h), únicamente mando a llamar main.hpp con #include "main.hpp".

Entendí bien?

Comment: No necesitas los pines, solo el tipo y el nombre; poniendo delante `extern`. El objeto se sigue creando en `main.cpp` (que has de dejar tal y como está o incluir tu nuevo `main.hpp`, da igual). Por lo demás, correcto.

Comment: Otra cosa, esta ya es mas técnica: El orden de creación de objetos es **INDEFINIDO** entre módulos. Eso quiere decir que puede darse el caso de que intentes usar el objeto desde otro módulo **antes** de que se instancie. Puede pasar. Edito la respuesta y te indico la forma *mas mejor* de hacerlo.

Comment: En mi programa tengo la opción de usar un lector SPI o I2C. El primer método que me sugeriste funcionó en el SPI, mientras que en el I2C me arroja un error con la librería.

Probé el segundo método, y en ambas versiones me arroja 'RC522' does not name a type y 'RC522' was not declared in this scope